# partial_update only if not exist (PATCH Django Rest Framework)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am currently using partial_update to update info but I want to update it only if that specific field is empty.

**views.py**

```
class TitleViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    queryset = Title.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TitleSerializer


    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class TitleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Title
        fields = ['pk', 'name', 'steam_appid', 'website', 'twitter']
```

So instead of updating for example 'twitter' field. I ONLY want to update if its empty. Also I dont want to specify 'twitter' as a field since I have many more.

Comment: So why not send only the fields that need updated from the client? that's the whole purpose of partial update - to update only what is needed, but the fields are left for the client to specify

Comment: Because the the server who sends just gives does a PATCH request. It is a different server and has no idea if it exists

Comment: But I guess I can make it aware, and only sent a PATCH if the data is different.

Comment: It could be better that way because you could end up with an unexpected behavior - the client server sends some updates, gets 200 and assumes the update was successful but the old values remain in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, it basically checks of the attribute is empty, if its not it does nothing. If it is empty, it will update it.

```
class TitleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Title
        fields = ['pk', 'name', 'steam_appid', 'website', 'twitter']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
            if not getattr(instance, attr):
                setattr(instance, attr, value)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: You are using instance.save(). This will trigger an update for all the fields. If you want to just update that specific attr do this instance.save(updated_fields=[attr])

Comment: Ah sweet, didnt knew that! 'update_fields' seems to be the correct name though